# Finding the mass of a curve having a specified linear density using a line integral

Tags: calculus, integration, line-integrals

I have some doubts whether the result I obtained is correct.
As the topic title says - I am looking for the mass of a curve with a density of $$\sigma(x,y)= \sqrt{x}$$
The curve K is described as follows:
$$x=y^2$$
$$y \in [-1,1]$$

Alright, so I begin with substituting 
$$y=t$$ 
I know that to calculate the mass of such a curve I need to use following equation
$$M=\int_{K}^{}\sigma dl$$
$$K(t)=(t^2,t)$$
$$K'(t)=(2t,1)$$
$$I=\int_{K}\sigma dl=\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{t^2}\sqrt{1+4t^2} dt$$
$$I=\frac{1}{8}\int_{-1}^{1}8t\sqrt{1+4t^2} dt$$
Which, due to the function being even is equal to:
$$I=2\frac{1}{8}\int_{0}^{1}8t\sqrt{1+4t^2} dt$$
Using substitution
$$1+4t^2=s$$
$$8tdt=ds$$
$$I=\frac{1}{4}\int_{1}^{5}s^{\frac{1}{2}} ds$$
$$I=\frac{1}{6}s^{\frac{3}{2}} dt$$
Which after substituting the limits is equal to 
$$\frac{1}{6}(\sqrt{125}-1)$$

However, Wolfram after giving it the first integral to solve - just prints that the result is 0.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't checked the entire computation, but you've done at least two things wrong. First, 
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{t^2}\sqrt{1+4t^2}\, dt = \int_{-1}^1 |t|\sqrt{1+4t^2}\,dt,$$
and then
$$\int_{-1}^1 |t|\sqrt{1+4t^2}\,dt$$
is an even function (the function you posted is an *odd* function, and indeed its integral is zero), so you can write
$$\int_{-1}^1 |t|\sqrt{1+4t^2}\,dt = 2\int_0^1 t\sqrt{1+4t^2}\,dt.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand why wolfram was giving me 0. Apparently my computation was right despite the mistake with the absolute value.